# Как быстрее обходить список (ArrayList) и вставлять в него элементы? Через ListIterator или созданием нового списка?

Tags: java, циклы, arraylist, итераторы

Есть следующая задача: имеется цикл по спискам элементов (ArrayList), содержащим в среднем около 15 элементов. Каждый раз мы вставляем в этот список примерно 1-2 элемента, причём в неопределенное место списка (т.е. может быть и начало, и конец, и середина). И в итоге нужно создавать копии этих списков и сохранять отдельно. Вижу 2 основных подхода: использование ListIterator - создание в цикле копии списка и вставка прямо по ходу цикла. И второй - создание нового списка и добавление в него по очереди всех элементов, в том числе и новых. С одной стороны, вставка в новый список будет занимать константное время, но возможны затраты на расширение массива, а ListIterator двигает элементы в массиве, которые находятся правее вставляемого. Но при этом часто слышу мнение, что нужно использовать Iterator. Как всё таки быстрее?

Comment: А сделать тест и повторить несколько сотен раз и сравнить не вариант наверное?

Comment: `` а ListIterator двигает элементы в массиве, которые находятся правее вставляемого`` - в смысле? У листИтератора есть метод `add()`, но любая вставка двигает элементы, а также любое расширение занимает время, хотя для `ArrayList` да с вашим количеством элементов это будет происходить аж 1 раз максимум. И вообще, вы понимаете разницу между `ListIterator` vs `Iterator`? И вообще - вам надо чтобы исходный лист оставался неизменным или все-таки вначале в него вносятся добавленные элементы, а потом делается копия его?

Comment: ... если неизменным, то создавайте новый лист, бегите итератором или `forEach` или стримами по исходному листу и добавляйте все что нужно в новый. Если нужно копировать измененную копию старого листа, то у есть конструктор, принимающий параметром коллекцию, а внутри копия происходит с помощью `arrayCopy()`, т.е. быстрее некуда

Comment: если вам нужен простой и короткий ответ : правильнее создавать новый экземпляр коллекции, но дело здесь совсем не в скорости.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, неправильно выразился конечно, сам ListIterator не двигает, но вставка именно в ArrayList ведёт к смещению элементов вправо. Всё верно, исходный неизменен, создаём новый и в него добавляем. Получается, что задача сводится к тому, что быстрее - добавлять по одному и по порядку или добавить разом и потом 1-2 раза добавить новый элемент.

Comment: @Дмитрий, а можно поподробнее пожалуйста?

Comment: Если известны индексы вставки, то создать новый быстрее, а потом вставить пару элементов. Если нет, например, нужно вставлять по условию, то все равно итератором бежать, тут надо смотреть куда чаще будут добавляться элементы - в конец или в начало

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець, мысль понял, спасибо!

Comment: @SLim это скорее тема 2-часовой лекции, чем предмет обсуждения на форуме... но думаю , что для начала нужно детально разобраться с final. ключевое слово - детально. это будет 1 шагом в понимании